# Error occurs when retriving data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

Hi I stored my **mp3** files inside **Storage** in Firebase. Set permissions under Rules tab to be:

```
      allow read, write, request;
```

In order to take the files from there I use react-axios.

When I load my page, I get an error that the request has been blocked by CORD policy:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'gs://******.appspot.com/****/****' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only 
supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, 
https.
```

I installed gsutil and then I ran the command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://****.appspot.com
```

I did not get any errors for running this command.

This is the cors.json file:

```
[ 
 {
  "origin": ["http://localhost:3000","gs://******.appspot.com"],
  "method": ["GET"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
]
```

However, when I load my website, I still get the same error...

Comment: The rules do not look ok. Refer the official docs to set them correctly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules

Comment: At this moment I don't care about authentications, so they are fine

Comment: Maybe you don't care but syntax of the rule is incorrect. If you are sure that authentication doesn't prevent uploads/download then use the `.getDownloadURL()` method of file reference to get valid URL for retrieving the file (it will have https: protocol, not gs:).

Comment: The details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states cross origin requests are only allowed for certain protocols. This is a security measure implemented in most browsers. If you are interested why this policiy is what it is, theres a good article on [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors) about that.

My suggested solution for that problem would be to setup a backend api server on that host as well, let it query the needed information from the db, add the necessary CORS headers, and send it to the browser running your frontend.

You could do that using node.js utilizing express.js.
Please see below example.

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function getmusicfunction(req, res) {
  console.log('GET /getmusic');
  # query the db for your file here and store it into your body bariable
  res.send(body);
}

const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.get('/getmusic', (req, res) => getmusicfunction(req, res));

const port = 6667;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('API listening on port ' + port + '!'));
```

EDIT: I confused Firebase with Firebird. Sorry. I withdraw that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key parts of the error message are:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

And

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
>   'gs://******.appspot.com/****/****' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'

You're trying to access a URL starting with `gs://` from JavaScript that runs on `http://`. Those are two different protocols, and the error message says that this is not allowed.

To download a file from Cloud Storage you typically use:

- either a download URL you generate for the file, which is a publicly readable (but unguessable) URL. The download URL starts with `https://` so is eligible for cross-original requests from your page. See the Firebase documentation on [downloading a file via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).
- <strike>or you use the Firebase SDK for accessing the data. The Firebase SDK uses its own protocol, which is not affected by the cross-origin requirements. You could use the `gs:` URL you now use with that SDK.</strike> It looks like this approach is not available in the JavaScript SDK.